# How to get the Voronoi diagram of some points to display in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, computational-geometry, cgal, voronoi

I have some points plotted on a QGraphicsScene in QT and have encapsulated them into a point class.  I want to compute and display the Voronoi diagram of thse points onto the scene.  What is the best way to do this?

I was thinking of using CGAL, but I can't find a good way to do this..

Answer (score 3):

What you need to display is the Voronoi diagram restricted to a rectangle (your display window). Here is a simple way to do it.

Relevant documentation pages [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_2_ref/Class_Delaunay_triangulation_2.html) and [there](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Kernel_23_ref/Class_Iso_rectangle_2.html).

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <iterator>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef K::Iso_rectangle_2 Iso_rectangle_2;
typedef K::Segment_2 Segment_2;
typedef K::Ray_2 Ray_2;
typedef K::Line_2 Line_2;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K>  Delaunay_triangulation_2;

//A class to recover Voronoi diagram from stream.
//Rays, lines and segments are cropped to a rectangle
//so that only segments are stored
struct Cropped_voronoi_from_delaunay{
  std::list<Segment_2> m_cropped_vd;
  Iso_rectangle_2 m_bbox;

  Cropped_voronoi_from_delaunay(const Iso_rectangle_2& bbox):m_bbox(bbox){}

  template <class RSL>
  void crop_and_extract_segment(const RSL& rsl){
    CGAL::Object obj = CGAL::intersection(rsl,m_bbox);
    const Segment_2* s=CGAL::object_cast<Segment_2>(&obj);
    if (s) m_cropped_vd.push_back(*s);
  }

  void operator<<(const Ray_2& ray)    { crop_and_extract_segment(ray); }
  void operator<<(const Line_2& line)  { crop_and_extract_segment(line); }
  void operator<<(const Segment_2& seg){ crop_and_extract_segment(seg); }
};

int main(){
  //consider some points
  std::vector<Point_2> points;
  points.push_back(Point_2(0,0));
  points.push_back(Point_2(1,1));
  points.push_back(Point_2(0,1));

  Delaunay_triangulation_2 dt2;
  //insert points into the triangulation
  dt2.insert(points.begin(),points.end());
  //construct a rectangle
  Iso_rectangle_2 bbox(-1,-1,2,2);
  Cropped_voronoi_from_delaunay vor(bbox);
  //extract the cropped Voronoi diagram
  dt2.draw_dual(vor);
  //print the cropped Voronoi diagram as segments
  std::copy(vor.m_cropped_vd.begin(),vor.m_cropped_vd.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<Segment_2>(std::cout,"\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you considered using the CGAL library, have you read [its section about Voronoi diagrams](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Voronoi_diagram_2/Chapter_main.html)? In the [Software Design](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Voronoi_diagram_2/Chapter_main.html#Section_45.2) subsection, they explain the data structures involved. From what I read, you can get the polygons which represent the Dirichlet cells, and from there you can tell Qt to draw and fill them with different colors (some World Map coloring algorithm might be useful here).